# How to write soap client if Request and Response classes are not provided

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, soap, soap-client

I am new at spring framework and web programming. I need to write client using spring boot. I was provided api and functions I need to use. As I discovered, provided web service uses soap which is new to me. I tried to follow the official spring guide: https://spring.io/guides/gs/consuming-web-service/
As I understood, I need to use Request and Response classes generated from wsdl to specify request and response objects for exchange. But in wsdl there are no such classes. I see similar names like getCarsListRequest and this is not xsd type(which are generating) but < message > 
[wsdl link](https://api.webdispecink.cz/code/WebDispecinkServiceNet.php?wsdl)

Comment: I think this can help you https://www.baeldung.com/maven-wsdl-stubs

Comment: Use the WSDL to generate the classes. Follow any basic Spring WebServices tutorial which will explain that.